# Plotly - how to add multiple regressions for each color using R?

Tags: r, plotly, regression

My plot is stacking all the regression lines on top of each other.

```
mod = lm(weight_kg ~ height_cm, data=rugby_data) 

fig2 <- plot_ly(rugby_data, x = ~height_cm, y = ~weight_kg, type="scatter", mode="markers", color = rugby_data$continent) %>% 
        add_lines(x = rugby_data$height_cm,y = fitted(mod), name="fitted", mode = "lines") %>%
  layout(title = 'Height Vs. Weight Scatter Plot', plot_bgcolor = "#e5ecf6")

fig2
```

[Image of code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVNN8.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `lm` object did not fit model by groups(I guess it's `continent`)

If your purpose is to plot the points and regression lines,

you may try using `ggplot2`.

As you did not provide your data, I use `iris` as an example.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

iris %>%
  ggplot(aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length, group = Species, color = Species)) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm") +
  geom_point()
```

[image]